# How would you group a field in a table so it doesnt show duplicates - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

On a webpage for an alumni group, I'm trying to manage teams, and in the teams table, I have the fields: year, team_category(Football, etc), and members(MtoM). I'm trying to show on the first page a list of categories but only one per field entry. Clicking on the category button would lead to a list of teams filtered by said category and show year and members of the team. So my example below would just be Football, Cheearleading, chess. How to I group by category or any potentially better method?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getTeams } from "../../../api/apiCalls";

const Teams = () => {
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getTeams()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setTeams(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="">
      <h1>
        Teams
        <hr />
      </h1>
      {teams.map((teams, index) => (
        <div className="" border="" key={teams.id}>
          <Link
            className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-warning m-1"
            to={`/dashboard/teams/${teams.category}/`}
          >
            {teams.category}
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Output for my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLDvo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce to only include the category once

```js
teams.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  return previousValue.some((team) => team.category === currentValue.category)
    ? previousValue
    : [...previousValue, currentValue];
}, []).map... your code here
```